# Change directory path name on URL for Admin in webforms

Tags: visual-studio-2013, webforms

I want to change url for Admin

*"../Account/Users/Page.aspx"*

It would show

*"../Account/Admin/Page.aspx"*

this without having to copy the pages for the admin folder. Is this possible to do?

[Project Directory Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3ash.png)